# Session variable doesn't persist during redirect in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I am making a redirect to homecontroller after user authenticates and set a auth token to session for use in the home controller as -

**Controller 1**

```
$secret = Crypt::encrypt($secret);
  Session::put('secret', $secret);
  Session::save();      
  return redirect()->action('loginController@homeRedirect');
```

**Controller 2 -> homeRedirect**

```
function homeRedirect(){
      dd(Session::all());
      if(Session::has('secret')){
        $secret = Session::get('secret');
        Session::forget('secret');
```

**Here the dump comes blank array.** nothing comes in the session, however if i test this `dd(Session::all())` then it gives correct details.

Also I have tried as sending data using `with('secret', $secret)` but that is also returning a blank session.

> My session.php file has following entry `'driver' => 'file',` and the laravel version is 5.2.

**EDIT**

Also if I try like this -

```
function homeRedirect(Request $request){
  $ses = $request->session()->get('secret');
  dd($ses);
```

Then I get error stating `Session store not set on request.`

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Laravel 5.2 , you should make sure you have set route for your `loginController@homeRedirect` in web middleware.

Your route should be defined in `routes.php` like so

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('/homeredirect','loginController@homeRedirect');
}
```

If it's defined this way:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {


}

Route::get('/homeredirect','loginController@homeRedirect');
```

it won't work