# Laravel 5.2 Redirect with Flash Data

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I just upgraded to Laravel 5.2 from 4.2 to try the new feature of the framework. But I have trouble on setting `flash session` data to be sent on other controller/route.

Here is my simple code:

**controller**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ctest extends Controller {

    public function page_a() {
        return redirect('page_b')->with('verified', 'Go to page B');
    }

    public function page_b(Request $request) {
        dd(array(
            session()->has('verified'),             // Option a
            $request->session()->get('verified')    // Option b
        ));
    }
}
```

**route**

```
// Old code
// Route::get('/page_a', 'ctest@page_a');
// Route::get('/page_b', 'ctest@page_b');

// As pointed out by @rishal at the comment,
// I tried using this group but I can't still get
// the flash data.
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/page_a', 'ctest@page_a');
    Route::get('/page_b', 'ctest@page_b');
});
```

**result on page_b**

```
array: [
  0 => false
  1 => null
]
```

I cannot figure out what's wrong with this. Whenever I got redirected to page_b, the session only contains `_token`, not including the `verified` flash session data that I already set on page_a.

**PS: I'am using database to store session not file**

Comment: did you try to group your route
Route::group

Comment: not yet. do I need to do that? why? :D Sorry. Im new to 5.2

Comment: have a look at this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34703696/session-variable-doesnt-persist-during-redirect-in-laravel?rq=1

Comment: i tried bro, but still same

Comment: according to the laravel doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session you retrieve session using request eg. $request->session()->get('key');

Comment: yes, i also tried that but no luck. I updated my question

Answer (score 2):

First you need to group your routes to get session variable after redirecting the page

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/page_a', 'ctest@page_a');
    Route::get('/page_b', 'ctest@page_b');
});
```

Next, use Request to retrieve session

```
public function page_b(Request $request) {
     if ($request->session()->has('verified'))
         echo $request->session()->get('key');
}
```

In your page_a this line

```
return redirect('page_b')->with('verified', 'Go to page B');
```

does not create session variables, it creates `$verified` with value of 'Go to page B'. Instead you can create session variable using

```
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot to include to my question that I use database for storing sessions and not file. does it affects the behaviour?

Comment: what do you mean affects the behavious? is it working or not?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing 'middleware' with 'middlewareGroups', like this :

```
Route::group(['middlewareGroups' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/page_a', 'ctest@page_a');
    Route::get('/page_b', 'ctest@page_b');
});
```

Hope this helps!